# How to test withRouter() and uselocation() wrapped component in React using jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I am getting below error. Please tell how to write test case to test a component wrapped in withRouter and component using useLocation()
●
Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.withRouter) is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the route component tree is not attached to the render method.

I recommend create a TestUtils which abstract the render from react-testing-library and the router hierarchy:

This would be more or less:

```
export const renderWithRouter = (
  children,
  {
    path = '/',
    initialRoute = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [initialRoute] })
  } = {}
) => {
  return {
    ...render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path={path}>{children}</Route>
      </Router>
    ),
    history
  };
};
```

Usage:

Without params in route:

```
const wrapper = renderWithRouter(<Component />);
```

With params in route:

```
const wrapper = renderWithRouter(<Component />, { path: '/route/:id', initialRoute: '/route/1' });
```

where :id will be replaced by 1

Comment: do we need to import withRouter in the test file?

Comment: no... just use renderWithRouter instead render from testing library

Comment: still getting error when i try to do expect(wrapper).tomatchsnapshot(); Error is TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.withRouter) is not a function

      21 | }
      22 |
    > 23 | export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);

Comment: can you show your app.js, index.js and your test file/utils?